# Проблема с jar на linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, raspbian

Есть приложение на java. 
Среда разработки - intellij idea.
Когда я его запускаю в Windows, все работает идеально. Но когда запускаю на Raspbian Jessie, то вылетает NoClassDefFoundError к библиотекам проекта.
Я пробовал через dependencies в project struture => module починить, не сработало.
Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Вы IDEA на Raspbian запустили?

Comment: @LEQADA Зачем. Я просто сделал jar на Windows, и залил на малинус.

Comment: @DenShDen АRM JDK установили, пути прописали в малинке?

Comment: @DenShDen, а причём тогда IDEA? Зачем вы его в тегах и в тексте вопроса упомянули?

Comment: Так а детали исключения? Какой класс он не нашёл? У меня малиныч, если что, имеется.

Comment: @D-side сначала не нашел библиотеку друга. После копирования ее исходников в /src с ней проблем нет. А сейчас не видит библиотеку для sqlite.

Comment: @DenShDen Опишите подробнее, в конце-концов, что делаете и как. Покажите структуру папок

Comment: @Владимир, да что я делаю-то. Беру, из Windows на git проект заливаю (с скомпилированным jar'ом в папке). Потом клонирую на малинуксе, и пытаюсь запустить jar. На windows все путем, на raspbian нет. Касательно структуры папок. Есть несколько подключенных библиотек, и есть сам проект. Устроено все предельно просто.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из самых распространенных причин `NoClassDefFoundError` + `.jar` - это отсутствие библиотек при загрузке классов. Одно из решений - это убедиться, что все библиотеки описанные в `Manifest` доступны там, где вы его запускаете.

Comment: @totorro, я понял, в чем ошибка. Я просто ни одной библиотеки не добавил в MANIFEST.