# Странный ClassNotFoundException в java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения, jar

Есть проект, написанный на java. При простом Run'e в Intellij Idea все прекрасно работает.
Как только делаю jar и запускаю его в IDE, вылетает `ClassNotFoundException`.
Вот полностью ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.fruitmix.trashbox.FirstSQliteEditor.Conn(FirstSQliteEditor.java:19)
at com.fruitmix.trashbox.FirstSQliteEditor.Start(FirstSQliteEditor.java:10)
at com.fruitmix.trashbox.ClientRuler.main(ClientRuler.java:31)
```

19 строчка в FirstSQliteEditor'e:

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

Сам драйвер прописан в Manifest.mf:

```
Class-Path: libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

Как можно исправить ошибку?

Comment: А как вы запускаете jar? Т.е. прям команду бы. Очевидно, что вы забыли прописать правильный classpath.

Comment: @Vartlok, делаю jar application, указываю файл и нажимаю Run в IDE.

Comment: Пробовали прописать руками classpath? в настройках VM `-classpath libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar`

Comment: @Vartlok, не пробовал.

Comment: Я надеюсь вы попробуете?) И если не заработает сообщите.

Comment: @Vartlok, еще варианты есть?

Comment: @DenShDen Если хотите получить решение проблемы, вопрос следует задать так, что-бы он был понятен не только для вас, а для тех людей, кто захочет Вам помочь. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484943/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-jar-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Может, кому-то будет полезно.

1. Идем создавать новый артефакт (`Project structure`=>`artefacts`).
2. Нажимаем на "+", выбираем jar.
3. Далее, `from modules with dependencies`.
4. Выпадает меню, выбираем "`extract to the target JAR`".
   Создается манифест потом, и все работает.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том что IDEA имеет свой встроенный `Manifest` и при запуске она перечисляет все `.jar` файлы которые должны участвовать в работе программы. `.jar` файлы не содержат в себе все библиотеки которые нужны для работы программы (в отличии от `.war` и `.ear`). поэтому нужно использовать `Manifest` и обеспечивать доступ к библиотеками при запуске `.jar` файла.

Comment: так и не понял, что делать нужно. Добавить эту строчку во встроенный? Если да, то как его найти.
Или я не так воспринял ваш ответ?

Comment: нужно добавить перечень jarов в classpath и при запуске чтобы они лежали там же (куда указывает classpath)

Comment: classpath в project structure=>artifacts=>Manifest properties?
Если да, то не срабатывает способ.

Comment: если запускается через IDE но не запускается jarом из терминала, то не видит просто приложение этих jarов

Comment: ключевой вопрос: почему? И как сделать так, чтоб видел.